# web worker containing xhr object with upload progress event handler

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, web-worker

I'm trying to create a worker that uploads file attached with event handler that will update progress bar in my html page. the upload is already working fine in the worker.

I know that web worker has no access to DOM objects, which is where all my progress bars are. so, I'm wondering if there's any work around? I want to do the uploads in worker, but I also want the progress tracking. I'll be uploading several file in parallel, so, each worker (upload) will have its own progress bar.
is this doable? or should I let go of web worker altogether and choose different design?

this is what's inside my worker

```
onmessage = e => {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.addEventListener('progress', function(e) {
            var done = e.position || e.loaded, total = e.totalSize || e.total;
            console.log('xhr progress: ' + (Math.floor(done/total*1000)/10) + '%');
        }, false);
        if ( xhr.upload ) {
            xhr.upload.onprogress = function(e) {
                var done = e.position || e.loaded, total = e.totalSize || e.total;
                console.log('xhr.upload progress: ' + done + ' / ' + total + ' = ' + (Math.floor(done/total*1000)/10) + '%');
            };
        }
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function(e) {
            if ( 4 == this.readyState ) {
                console.log(['xhr upload complete', e]);
            }
        };
        xhr.open('post', url, true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","multipart/form-data");
        let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("thefile", e.data.payload);
        xhr.send(formData)
}
```

I already prepared some event handler, but currently, it's just logging.

Thanks

Comment: This is doable. Please add your current code so we can point you in the right direction at the right spot in the code to add your progress bars.

Comment: great! ok, hang on. will post the snippet shortly

Comment: @NetByMatt uploaded the content of my worker.

Comment: Why do you want to do the upload from the Worker exactly? A Network request is already "not-done" by the current CPU thread, it thus won't block your UI anyway. On the other hand, starting a Worker is an heavy operation, if you do it too often then you might start to see a deterioration in your perfs. All in all, this exact code is best kept on the main thread. If you did manipulate the data before sending it, then that could make sense to offload that processing to the Worker, but as it's currently, that's probably a bad idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `onmessage` events includes a `.source` property. This is how you send data back to the client. Inside your progress event listener you would add something like:

```
e.source.postMessage({uploadName: <unique name>, progress: done});
```

Watch out, though. You use `e` as both the onmessage handler data and the progress event handler. I would recommend making the names of the two unique.

Then in your page you listen for the message:

```
window.addEventListener('message', (data) => {
  // ... read data.progress and send it to the right place on the page
}
```